# Overriding GetHashCode() to Determine Shared Edges in a Graph in C#?

Tags: c#, hash, graph, hashmap, mesh

I've been working on some code that's meant to procedurally subdivide a 3D mesh (basically, a graph structure). It's roughly based on the [implementation in the selected answer over here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/259127/does-anyone-have-any-code-to-subdivide-a-mesh-and.html).

In the suggested implementation, Bunny83 uses a C# dictionary to keep track of each unique polygon edge. This is necessary because in this kind of task many edges will be shared between adjacent polygons. If you look at this section of his code (full code sample is in the link above), you can see how he determines the location a new vertex between two existing vertices (passed as function parameters):

```
static int GetNewVertex(int i1, int i2)
 {
     // We have to test both directions since the edge
     // could be reversed in another triangle
     uint t1 = ((uint)i1 << 16) | (uint)i2;
     uint t2 = ((uint)i2 << 16) | (uint)i1;
     if (newVectices.ContainsKey(t2))
         return newVectices[t2];
     if (newVectices.ContainsKey(t1))
         return newVectices[t1];
     // generate vertex:
     int newIndex = vertices.Count;
     newVectices.Add(t1,newIndex);

     // calculate new vertex
     vertices.Add((vertices[i1] + vertices[i2]) * 0.5f);
     normals.Add((normals[i1] + normals[i2]).normalized);
     // [... all other vertex data arrays]

     return newIndex;
 }
```

As you can see, for his dictionary, he uses a bit shifting trick to create unique keys for each edge (pair of vertices). Basically, he takes the unique index IDs of each vertex (int i1 and int i2) and concatenates them using bitwise operators to create two new uint-sized keys which could represent that edge.

While this is a cool technique, I'm curious if there are some better ways to achieve this result..

From what I understand he's essentially creating a unique hash value for each set of polygons, and then using that hash value to retrieve the ID of the vertex that bisects that edge, if it exists. If not, he adds that edge and the ID of the bisecting vertex to the dictionary.

---

**Here's what I was thinking about doing instead:**

```
class Edge {
    int vertIndex1;
    int vertIndex2;

    public Edge(int vertIndex1, vertIndex2)
    {
        this.vertIndex1 = vertIndex1;
        this.vertIndex2 = vertIndex2;
    }

    public override uint GetHashCode()
    {
        //Some hashing function here..
        //returns a number value that's unique to this edge
        //but also works in both 'directions' (if possible)
    }
}

//Modified..
static int GetNewVertex(int i1, int i2)
 {
     Edge currentEdge = new Edge( i1, i2 );

     uint edgeHash = currentEdge.GetHashCode();
     if (newVectices.ContainsKey( edgeHash ))
         return newVectices[ edgeHash ];

     // generate vertex:
     int newIndex = vertices.Count;
     newVectices.Add(edgeHash, newIndex);

     // calculate new vertex
     vertices.Add((vertices[i1] + vertices[i2]) * 0.5f);
     normals.Add((normals[i1] + normals[i2]).normalized);
     // [... all other vertex data arrays]

     return newIndex;
 }
```

To me this seems like it would be more readable, and if I'm able to find a better way of hashing the edges it would be faster and it might work in both directions (i.e.: the indices within the vertex are stored the other way around, a common occurrence when dealing with triangle indices). Because I'm essentially looking for duplicate pairs of numbers in multiple various array slots, I can't simply use memory addresses for hashing..

So, is this a reasonable/right/non-stupid approach? Is it worth doing, and will this approach allow me to identify specific edges better than the original snippet?

Comment: 1) Hashes aren't usually guaranteed to be unique. They're just a good "first pass" at equality. 2) If you override `GetHashCode` without overriding `Equals`, you'll get a warning (or possibly an error; I can't remember offhand). 3) You can't override `Equals` and return a `uint` - it's declared to return `int`.

Comment: I might be wrong here, but isn't the original "((uint)i1 << 16) | (uint)i2;" an example of a unique hash of two integers? (Although if statement 2&3 are right, then using uint might be a showstopper anyway..)

Comment: Nope. The hash for (0, 65536) is the same as the hash for (1, 0). And that's *fine* for a hash function. (Using `|` isn't generally the best idea, but that's a different matter.) See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx

Comment: `GetHashCode` returns an `int`. How would any combination of more than one `int` result in a "unique" hash? See also [Pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the insight. Maybe I need to go back to the drawing board on this.. Or maybe i don't need truly 'unique' hashes (especially if that's impossible, haha) for mesh subdivision. Unless the odds of hash collisions within a set of neighboring vertices is so low that the odds are on my side regardless..? - I'd hate to rely on 'luck'...

Comment: It seems like you don't really want/need a hash, but something like a `key` or `id` to uniquely identify an object. If the two `int` values truly uniquely identify the object, then maybe you could use a `long` value that's a combination of the two `int` values. Something like `(((long)i1) << 32) + i2` maybe (untested).

Comment: Yeah. So each vertex is stored only *once* in an array, and a second array of int indices is used to refer to the draw order of each vertex. Because many connected triangles share verts, the same indices will show up in different array slots. Basically I need to do something like that to create an identifier for each edge, so I can whatever vertex lies on that edge.. Maybe I just have my terminology mixed up, because I thought that type of key generation was a form of 'hasing'. I'm a relatively new coder!

Comment: Hashing in this case is basically "putting stuff into buckets". So that later, when you want to find them again, you only have to find the right bucket *and then look inside that bucket* to find the item you want. The most important thing is, that there could be more than one item in one bucket. That's why `GetHashCode` doesn't make a lot of sense without `Equals`. `GetHashCode` determines, which bucket to put the item into. And if there are more than one item in one bucket, `Equals` determines the exact item you want.

Comment: If you (uniquely) identify your items by a key, then that key could be the basis of both `GetHashCode` and `Equals`. You *could* overwrite them like `public override int GetHashCode() { return Key.GetHashCode(); }` and `public override bool Equals(object obj) { return obj is Edge && ((Edge)obj).Key.Equals(Key); }`. But again, the way it seems you want to use it, it is not absolutely necessary. Just work with the key.